# Exceptions after changing to developer mode

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, widgets

After I changed to developer mode, I can't view the main page, and get the following exception (Magento 2.1.2)

```
Invalid XML in file x.com/app/code/Ves/ImageSlider/etc/widget.xml:
Element 'description': This element is not expected. Expected is ( value ).
```

The issue is labelled to be at this area of the xml file

```
<parameter name="autoplay_timeout" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Autoplay Timeout</label>
    <depends><parameter name="autoplay" value="1" /></depends>
    <description translate="true"><![CDATA[Default: 3000]]></description>
    <value>3000</value>
</parameter>
<parameter name="autoplay_speed" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Autoplay Speed</label>
    <depends><parameter name="autoplay" value="1" /></depends>
    <description translate="true"><![CDATA[Default: 800]]></description>
    <value>800</value>
</parameter>
```

Comment: What's the content of `app/code/Ves/ImageSlider/etc/widget.xml` ?

Comment: Do you want me to post the file or just the part that is labelled as the problem?

Comment: the file please

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think I can share the file to avoid any issues with the developers of the theme, but the area with the issue is posted as an edit now, if that can be of any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move the `description` tag above the `depends` tag.
In the XSD schema `Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd` the parameter type is defined as this

```
 <xs:complexType name="parameterType" abstract="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Abstract type which is parent of all parameters. Contains attributes
            and elements common across all parameter types.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="label" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="description" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="depends" type="dependsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="visible" type="xs:boolean" />
    <xs:attribute name="sort_order" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

focus on this part

```
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="label" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="description" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="depends" type="dependsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
     </xs:sequence>
```

This means that the element `parameter` supports the child elements listed in the sequence tag in this order.  `label, description, depends`.

Side node: Ignore the fact that you don't see the `value` tag in here. This is added later in the same file depending on the value of the parameter `type`